# How to make my "transparent Image" Transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was picking an Html logo image with a transparent background. And when I try to add it to my repo it doesn't work. All it shows is this. [Html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaABO.png)

Comment: Shere you image url and code, because i think it's issue with images itself, so i just wanna confirm it

Comment: You should get the official one: https://www.w3.org/html/logo/#downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because its a fake png .
People put them for unknown reasons.
Try opening image in new tab to see if it has a background.
Edit: opening in new tab doesn't check if it's transparent you just have to download it

Answer (score 3):

It seems the image doesn't have a transparent background.
I suggest you find another image to use.

I think this is what you're looking for:

[image]